# can we delete @ sign if it's exist more than 2 times in the same line in python

Tags: python

the example of the file is as this

```
hello @ what are  @ you doing @ go there @ Today
we are @ here for you don't go a way @ Friend
```

As you see in the first line there are more than @ (4)
I want to make a code that check the exist of @ in the line and if it exist more than 2 as in the first line it deletes number 2 and 3 and keep 1 and 4

is this possible?

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: Hello! I advise you to check out [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/11082165).

Comment: How can be done? @superb rain

Comment: What have you tried? We expect people to make an attempt at solving a problem and to post the code that they are having problems with. (And what rule governs deleting the second and third but keeping the fourth `@`?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this can be done, and is a good question to ask. Here's how I would do it.

```
def clean(s):
    while s.count("@") > 2:
        s = "".join(s.rsplit("@",1))
    return s

print(clean("hello @ what are  @ you doing @ go there @ Today"))
print(clean("we are @ here for you don't go a way @ Friend"))
```

Hope this helps! Have a good day.

To just keep the first and last, you could do:

```
def clean(s):
    B = [i for i,v in enumerate(s) if v == "@"]
    C = [B[0],B[-1]] # Which ones to keep.
    for b in B[::-1]:
        if b in C: continue
        s = s[:b] + s[b+1:]
    return s

print(clean("hello @ what are  @ you doing @ go there @ Today"))
print(clean("we are @ here for you don't go a way @ Friend"))
```

Comment: thanks 1M times but I want to delete @ number 2 and 3 and keep number 1 and 4 is this possible?@jimmyCarlos

Comment: Exactly as I want . Don't know how to thanks you. Just I want to say Thanks a lot a nd appreciate what you have done.

Answer (score 2):

Should be a clean solution, where it will leave the first and last @, but clean out the others:

```
import re

def clean(line):
  if not len(re.findall('@', line)) > 2:
    return line
  start, tmp = line.split('@', 1) 
  middle, end = tmp.rsplit('@', 1)
  middle = middle.replace('@', '')
  result = "{}@{}@{}".format(start, middle, end)
  return result

print(clean("hello @ what are @ you doing @ go there @ Today"))
print(clean("we are @ here for you don't go a way @ Friend"))
```